# Replacing file or directory in local Git repo with upstream

Tags: git, github

I am trying to use the `git checkout upstream/master -- my-directory-here` command to replace a directory in my local fork of the Huggingface transformers library with the upstream version. But when I do this, nothing actually changes; all the differences between my version and the upstream are still there. I feel like I must be making some really obvious mistake, but I can't figure out what it is.

Photo: [What I get when I use git checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsUr.png)

Comment: The following commands outputs would help: ```git remote -v```, ```git branch -a```, ```ls -al```. My guess, is that your remote is not called ```upstream```, but ```origin```, so you would probably run: ```git checkout origin/master -- my-directory-here```.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @azbarcea. I tried what you suggested (using origin/master instead of upstream/master), but it didn't give me what I want, probably because I actually have two remote repos- one called `upstream`, and one called `origin`. `origin` is the GitHub repo for my fork, and `upstream` is the `huggingface/transformers` repo.Weirdly, I also tried copying the upstream repo into a local branch called `clean` with `git checkout upstream/master` and then `git switch -c clean`, and then using `git checkout clean -- examples/distillation`, and this also did nothing.

Comment: UPDATE: I'm noticing that when I do `git checkout clean -- examples/distillation`, it does replace the *modified* files in my local master branch with the versions from the clean branch, but 1) this does not show up in `git diff` (do I need to commit the changes for that to happen?), and 2) the files I *added* in my local master branch are not removed.

Comment: provide the output for ```git remote -v``` because you seem to have ```origin``` and ```huggingface``` remotes. Your replies are confusing ... Please update your question. To checkout you have to do it like: ```git checkout -b master upstream/master```, otherwise you end up on a SHA (commit) that may confuse you where you are. Use ```gitk --all &``` to understand your tree and where your ```HEAD``` (the current state/pointer of your commit history tree)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout partially will not bring any history log, this command will just replace the files.

Possibilities:

If you are in another branch, the command `git checkout upstream/master -- my-directory-here` will overwrite the files of your branch using the upstream/master version and stage automatically. Otherwise if your branch point to the same branch will revert to the `upstream/master` version.

If the files are staged, using `git diff` without any option, when the file is staged will not show any difference. Then use the `git diff --staged` option, you will able to see the differences against your current branch.

If your overwriting occurred successfully `git diff upstream/master examples/distillation` will not show any difference.

If you are in another branch, the files are not cleaned because you are just overwriting your files with the version from `upstream/master` not really checkout to a new branch.

To checkout to a new branch (fully, not partially), you can use `git checkout upstream/master -b name_of_new_branch`.

If are you trying just to clean your directory and the file keeps there, maybe its a git issue. When this happens, I commit what needed and clone the entire repo again, because it is a mystery why the git keeps the changes.